# WFA How do I get the line number where the caret is on in a textbox

Tags: c#

```
int lineNumberLive = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
textBoxLineNumber.Text = lineNumberLive.ToString();
```

The above code sample does give me the line number output to a second textbox.
However, I notice that TextBox lines are limited to 1024 characters and anything longer gets wrapped and then from that point on your line numbers are wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a custom text box that allows longer lines. Or, I guess you could pre-process the text making note of which lines are longer than 1024 and build a line number translation table.

Comment: Sorry that is not a way I will go.